# An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, video-streaming, video-processing

I am trying capture the frames of a video stream using C#. When ever I run the code I keep getting the below given  error. I know there already few threads on SO that enlist this issue but none of them has any solution to my problem.

> *An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll Additional information: Attempted
>   to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that
>   other memory is corrupt.*

I have done fair  bit of research but have not been able to fix this issue.
Is it an issue with the video file or the Visual Studio itself?

Here is the code where I am stuck:

```
 try
            {
                if (openVideoStream(videoFile, out mediaDet, out mediaType))
                {
                    return getVideoSize(mediaType);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (mediaDet != null)
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mediaDet);
            }
            return Size.Empty;
        }

        private static Size getVideoSize(_AMMediaType mediaType)
        {
```

//This Line produces the error

```
            **WinStructs.VIDEOINFOHEADER videoInfo = (WinStructs.VIDEOINFOHEADER)Marshal.PtrToStructure(mediaType.pbFormat, typeof(WinStructs.VIDEOINFOHEADER));**

            return new Size(videoInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth, videoInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight);
        }
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: @MariusUt : I have posted the code..